# Using filter in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

I had a question where i needed to find how many people have the word "Chief" in their jobtitle?
i was using the below two approaches but both of them give different answers, kindly let me know what's the difference and which should i use.

Approach 1:

```py
len(sal[sal.JobTitle.str.contains("Chief", case=True, na=False)])
```

This gives output as 423

Approach 2:

```py
count = 0
for job in sal['JobTitle']:
    for j in job.split():
        if j.lower() =='chief':
            count+=1
            print(count)
```

This gives the correct output 477.

Comment: Use `case=False` in the first code. Also, you might have rows with multiple occurrences of "chief" in the same string, you count them in the second approach, not the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of your approach 1 count 'Chief' but approach 2 first lower and thencount 'chief'. It is possible to there were some records with lowercase in job title and approach 1 can not count them